# Tcl/Tk - can't read "UserArray": variable is array

Tags: arrays, debugging, tcl, tk-toolkit, tcldevkit

I am using ActiveState's TclDevKit debugger to look through my code but at one point in the execution of the program I get the following error:

```
can't read "UserArray": variable is array
    while executing
"set UserArray"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_uplevelCmd DbgNub_uplevelCmd $args"
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 [list set $name]"
    (procedure "DbgNub_TraceVar" line 53)
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_TraceVar 1 array UserArray time1_satOTRS1,2 w"
    (write trace on "UserArray(time1_satOTRS1,2)")
    invoked from within
"set UserArray($item,$window) $profile_array($item)"
```

This error utterly baffles me because as I understand Tcl/Tk, what I am doing is completely valid and legal. The code goes:

```
foreach item [array names profile_array] {
    set UserArray($item,$window) $profile_array($item)
}
```

In Tcl one is allowed to read from and write to an index in an array, I don't think there should be an error here... Am I missing some detail?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, at the line:

```
uplevel 1 [list set $name]
```

I guess that in your case, `$name == "UserArray"`. The above statement will be executed at the previous stack frame as:

```
set UserLevel
```

which does not make sense, as `UserLevel` is an array--that's what the error message is trying to tell you. I wonder if you really mean:

```
upvar 1 $name UserArray
```

in order to access the array from a `proc`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that code seems to be inside the TclDevKit debugger

Comment: The debugger has a bug? Nooooooooo! (Has it been reported yet?)

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, but the way the Debugger instruments files is rather annoying. When setting file paths with something like [file dirname [info script]] the code will actually return the pathname of the TclDebugger - not the location of the script! So I've had to move my entire working environment into the bin directory of the TclDevKit to get the debugger to work, hahahaha.